# Simplest way to get a URI from an attribute value?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, uri, xml-namespaces

In my XML, I have an element like

```
<myElement myAttribute="myNamespacePrefix:foobar"/>
```

There is a xmlns declaration in this file:

```
<xmlns:myNamespacePrefix="http://www.mydomain.com/blah#"/>
```

I want to make a URI from the value of myAttribute.

IE, I want:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blah#foobar
```

Sounds simple, doesn't it?

So what is the simple solution?

I couldn't find anything in the Framework or on MSDN,  so I just had to write this no-doubt bug-ridden mess:

```
public static Uri GetUri(string value, XElement containingElement)
        {
            if (value.Contains(":"))
            {

                var prefix = String.Concat(value.TakeWhile(c => c != ':'));
                XNamespace ns;
                if (containingElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(prefix) != null)
                    ns = containingElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(prefix);
                else ns = containingElement.GetDefaultNamespace();
                var localName = String.Concat(value.SkipWhile(c => c != ':').Skip(1));
                Contract.Assert(ns != null);
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ns.NamespaceName))
                    return new Uri(value);  
                else
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ns.NamespaceName);
                    if (!ns.NamespaceName.EndsWith("#"))
                    {
                        sb.Append('#');
                    }

                    return new Uri(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}{1}", sb.ToString(), localName));
                } 

            }
            else // no namespace prefix
            {
                String fragment;
                if (!value.StartsWith("#"))
                    fragment = value.Insert(0, "#");
                else
                    fragment = value;
                var uriString = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}{1}", containingElement.BaseUri, fragment);
                return new Uri(uriString);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. Do you just want to get the value of the myAttribute attribute and turn it into a Uri?

Comment: Yes.  A fully qualified URI of course.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some XML-related stuff recently. This is an example of what I used to get information from the XML in C#:

```
XmlDocument XML = new XmlDocument();
XML.LoadXml(/* XML data in string format goes here */);
```

Then you can do things like the following:

```
if (XML["myElement"] != null)
{
    string myAttributeStr = XML["myElement"].Attributes["myAttribute"].Value.ToString().Trim();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank.  That code doesn't look like it is sensitive to namespace prefixes however.

Comment: Mhmm try having a look at the XMLDocument class and what it can do to suit your needs. There is a property called 'NamespaceURI' that may work for this.

Comment: This looks like it is only for xml elements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.namespaceuri.aspx